# How to capture upto first event if event there else all events till now in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a click data of an app for users which is continuously updated in real time

```
Used id Events  Timestamp
u1     login    9:01
u1     start    9:05
u1     buy      9:10
u2     login    11:33
u2     cart     11:40
u3     login    15:03
u3     buy      15:10
u1     login    17:25
u1     buy      17:35
u4     login    18:33
u4     news     18:35
u3     news     19:09
u5     notifications    20:10
```

Expected output will have data upto first buy event or if buy not present then up to all events till now i.e. `current_timestamp()`.

```
Used id Events  Timestamp
u1     login    9:01
u1     start    9:05
u1     buy      9:10
u2     login    11:33
u2     cart     11:40
u3     login    15:03
u3     buy      15:10
u4     login    18:33
u4     news     18:35
u5     notifications    20:10
```

I want to capture the real time state of users upto first buy only and don't want to add after events for my machine learning use case which is first buy.
I don't know that's right way to do for this type of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case when` with `min` over a partitioned window to get the first buy timestamp, while using the current timestamp as the fallback in case there were no buy events. Then you can filter the rows with the time earlier than that timestamp. I used IST time zone to match where you are (according to your profile).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

spark.sql('set spark.sql.session.timeZone = IST')

result = df.withColumn(
    'first_buy',
    F.date_format(
        F.coalesce(
            F.min(
                F.when(
                    F.col('Events') == 'buy', F.col('Timestamp').cast('timestamp')
                )
            ).over(Window.partitionBy('User_id')),
            F.current_timestamp()
        ),
       'H:mm'
   )
).filter(
    'timestamp(Timestamp) <= timestamp(first_buy)'
).drop('first_buy').orderBy('User_id', F.col('Timestamp').cast('timestamp'))

result.show()
+-------+-------------+---------+
|User_id|       Events|Timestamp|
+-------+-------------+---------+
|     u1|        login|     9:01|
|     u1|        start|     9:05|
|     u1|          buy|     9:10|
|     u2|        login|    11:33|
|     u2|         cart|    11:40|
|     u3|        login|    15:03|
|     u3|          buy|    15:10|
|     u4|        login|    18:33|
|     u4|         news|    18:35|
|     u5|notifications|    20:10|
+-------+-------------+---------+
```