# Do we need to save and load pipeline and model separately in Pyspark ML?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I am doing steps such as data engineering and building some columns , Below I am building pipeline for our Spark ML model

```
stages = []

for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(
        inputCol=categoricalCol, outputCol=categoricalCol + "Index"
    )
    encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(
        inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()],
        outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"],
    )
    stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]


label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol="BSConfirmBuy", outputCol="label")
stages += [label_stringIdx]


numericCols = new_col_array

assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in categoricalColumns] + numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(new_df1)
new_df1 = pipelineModel.transform(new_df1)


##Model
gbt = GBTClassifier(maxIter=10)
gbtModel = gbt.fit(train)
predictions = gbtModel.transform(test)
```

In the above steps I was able to do pipeline and preidct using  gbtree.
Now I am saving

```
#Save pipeline
pipelineModel.write().overwrite().save("s3://data-production/pipelineModel_v1")

#Save Model
gbtModel.save("s3://data-production/first_trade.model_v0")
```

Now in production /future datasets, Do I need to load both pipeline and model ?

```
pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load("s3://data-production/pipelineModel_v1")

new_test= pipelineModel.transform(new_df1)

model = GBTClassifier.load("s3://data-production/first_trade.model_v0")
pred = gbtModel.transform(new_test)
```

Where new_test is future/production dataset

Comment: I think the pipeline file should include the model... but you can just test it on a small dataset and see if it runs

Comment: All the examples which I have gone through, has model seperately , so should I add model in pipeline stages as well?

Comment: why don't you just try both and see if they work?

Comment: I have tried loading both in production , and then there i get a column mismatch error in production/future dataset after pipeline transform method

Comment: the models have fixed column names. you need to make sure your future dataset has the same column names.

Comment: any work-around there ,If i have 10 k plus columns in data in training?

Comment: if the column names changed, how on earth can the model know which column names to use?

Comment: I have a events data, so I do pivoting and have data in columns, which results in data with huge dimensions in columns 10k for eg. While in future dataset we wont have such case, similar data mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796110/how-to-capture-upto-first-event-if-event-there-else-all-events-till-now-in-pyspa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228395/discussion-between-shubh-and-mck).